# reactjs state array property undefined after setting it

Tags: reactjs

I am struggling to understand why I am unable to access the sections state array element after setting it and displaying all the contents correctly. The error is occurring when I console log the [0] element of the sections state array. I have pasted console log output below as well.

```
// Load the course template 
  this.props.firebase
  .course(authUser.courseId)
  .get()
  .then((course) => {
    if (course.exists) {
      console.log("Course data:", course.data());
      this.setState({shortCode: course.data().shortCode});
      this.setState({title: course.data().title},()=>{
        let activities = [];
        course.data().sections.map(sect=>{
          this.props.firebase.getDocByIdFrom("courseActivities",sect.id)
          .get()
          .then((activity)=>{
            activities.push(activity.data()); 
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        });  
        this.setState({sections:activities},()=>{
          console.log("SECTIONS ",this.state.sections);
          console.log("SECTION 0 "+this.state.sections[0].title);
        });  
      });
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such course!");
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15WZM20Z0qlgHotjiRR4l5uWYDGl260Lh)

Comment: I find your code difficult to reason about. In any case, if `getDocByIdFrom` is async aren't you doing those logs and setState before it might be finished?

Comment: `get().then(...)` is asynchronous, when you set `this.setState({sections:activities}`,  `activities` won't have any contents yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following will ensure all the `.get()` operations have occurred before loading actitivies into state:

```
let activities = [];
Promise.all(course.data().sections.map(sect => {
  return this.props.firebase.getDocByIdFrom("courseActivities", sect.id)
    .get()
    .then(activity => activities.push(activity.data()))
  }))
.then(() => {
  this.setState({ sections:activities }, ()=>{
    console.log("SECTIONS ",this.state.sections);
    console.log("SECTION 0 "+this.state.sections[0].title);
  }); 
});
```